# Create category column depending on another column in R

Tags: r

I have data where each oberservation (row) has a unique `id`.
Depending on the first letter of that `id` the observations can be diveded into two groups. I want a column/variable to identify the group.

The following code works. But my question is if there is a more elegant R-way to do this?

```
> df <- data.frame(id = c("C-1", "P-2", "P-3", "C-2"))
> df$tmp_id <- startsWith(as.character(df$id), "C-")
> df
   id tmp_id
1 C-1   TRUE
2 P-2  FALSE
3 P-3  FALSE
4 C-2   TRUE
> df$typ[df$tmp_id == TRUE] <- "C"
> df$typ[df$tmp_id == FALSE] <- "P"
> df$typ <- factor(df$typ, levels=c("C", "P"), labels=c("Cheese", "Pork"))
> df
   id tmp_id    typ
1 C-1   TRUE Cheese
2 P-2  FALSE   Pork
3 P-3  FALSE   Pork
4 C-2   TRUE Cheese
> df$tmp_id <- NULL
> df
   id    typ
1 C-1 Cheese
2 P-2   Pork
3 P-3   Pork
4 C-2 Cheese
```

And an **extension** of my question is how I would deal this situation if I had more then two groups? e. g. `Cheese`, `Pork`, `Candy`, `Chocolate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to create a named vector, say `types`, to use as
a lookup table to link the prefixes to the groups. Then you can extract the
prefix from the `id` column and index the lookup vector to find the
corresponding group name:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c("C-1", "P-2", "P-3", "C-2"))

types <- c(C = "Cheese", P = "Pork")
df$typ <- types[substr(df$id, 1, 1)]

df
#>    id    typ
#> 1 C-1 Cheese
#> 2 P-2   Pork
#> 3 P-3   Pork
#> 4 C-2 Cheese
```

If you wanted to add additional groups, all you need to do is to add further
prefix-group mappings to the vector acting as a lookup table:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c("Ch-1", "Po-2", "Po-3", "Ca-2"))

types <- c(Ca = "Candy", Ch = "Cheese", Po = "Pork")
df$typ <- types[substr(df$id, 1, 2)]

df
#>     id    typ
#> 1 Ch-1 Cheese
#> 2 Po-2   Pork
#> 3 Po-3   Pork
#> 4 Ca-2  Candy
```

If you wanted to allow for varying-length prefixes, then you might want to
have a look at regular expressions for extracting them from the `id` column.

Created on 2018-05-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Line number 3 (`types`...) is interesting! I have never seen a syntax like that. Why can you write `Ca` without quotes? Do you have link to the relevant basic part of the R docu?

Comment: But `df$typ` is `character` not `factor`. Here would simply add this line `df$typ <- factor(df$typ, levels=c("C", "P"), labels=c("Cheese", "Pork"))` or is there a much more elegant way again? ;)

Comment: I never actually thought about the naming in `c`, but if you supply argument names for it, they will be used to create names for the resulting vector. I can't seem to find documentation for that behaviour. With regards to getting a `factor`, it would be easiest to just use `as.factor`: `df$typ <- as.factor(types[substr(df$id, 1, 1)])`. Unless you want the factor levels in a specific order, in which case `factor` like you suggest would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` package can handle this eloquently. I think what you are after if a `flagging` or `flag` variable/column. This will tell you which rows meet a certain condition and those that do not. The following code will generate a flag coded as `1` for all rows that start have a `C` in the `id` column. The `type` column is just another flag and can be created the same way, with an `ifelse` statement.

```
require(dplyr)

df <-  data.frame(id = c("C-1", "P-2", "P-3", "C-2")) # OP's dataset

df %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(str_detect(id,'C'),1,0), # mutate adds columns
         type = ifelse(flag == 1,'Cheese','Pork')) 


# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id     flag type  
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 C- 1   1.00 Cheese
2 P- 2   0    Pork  
3 P- 3   0    Pork  
4 C- 4   1.00 Cheese
```